# How to convert documents to .djvu format

Tags: conversion, documents, djvu

I'm looking for a plug-in or program to convert some of my documents to .djvu format. My documents are mostly in Excel, Word, PowerPoint, .PDF and .TXT format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the product list at [Overview of the DjVu Compression Software](http://www.djvuzone.org/support/tutorial/chapter-compress.html#compr-soft).

In addition, see:
[Pdf To Djvu GUI v. 2.0 ( Freeware )](http://www.trustfm.net/GeneralTools/SoftwarePdfToDjvuGUI.php?b2=1)
[Document Express with DjVu](http://www.caminova.net/en/products/) (somewhat outdated software)