# Convert word to djvu file format?

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, file-types, djvu

I want to convert word documents to djvu format, but I can't find any software that can do that. Can someone recommend to me a online converter od some software that can do that? I really need this because I need it for school.

Thank you in advance.

p.s. I noticed that there is the same [question](https://superuser.com/questions/80822/how-to-convert-documents-to-djvu-format) but the link for the download is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Word it is easy to save the file to PDF. Since Office 2010, Word has a built-in Save as PDF function, for version 2007 you can download a plugin from Microsoft website for free. With older versions, you can install one of the various free PDF printers that you can find online.

Once you have the PDF file, there are many programs that convert from PDF to DJVU. For example, the command line tool `pdf2djvu` available for download [here](https://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/). If you prefer a graphical interface, you can use [PDF to DJVU GUI](http://www.trustfm.net/GeneralTools/SoftwarePdfToDjvuGUI.php?b2=1).

**EDIT** How to use `pdf2djvu` from the command line

First, download the [zip file](https://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/downloads/detail?name=pdf2djvu-win32_0.7.14.zip&can=2&q=) containing the program files and extract them to some folder. Take note of the path where you extracted them to.
[Open a command prompt](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/f/open-command-prompt.htm) and navigate to the folder where you extracted the files using the command (I use an example path, which you must replace with your specific path)

```
cd C:\pdf2djvu-0.7.14
```

Now use the following command

```
pdf2djvu.exe pdf_file_path.pdf -o outputfile.djvu
```

where `pdf_file_path.pdf` is the complete path to the PDF file (e.g. `"C:\Users\John Doe\Documents\pdf_file.pdf"`, double quotes if your path includes spaces) and `outputfile.djvu` is the output file. If you don't specify a path then the file will be created in the program folder. The program will report its progress.

Notice that you can set options for the djvu file such as resolution, page size etc.

If you have a large number of files to convert we can work on an automated script.

Comment: Is this program compatible with Windows 7? I tried it on Windows 7 but the conversion was not successful.

Comment: @ZlateWay, How was it not successful? Was the file generated at all or was there an error?

Comment: @Pincopallino The file is generated, but I can't find it in the same directory as the pdf I choose to convert. The console window appears and after a few moments it disappears. I don't know what's the problem. I changed the compatibility and I tried to run the program as administrator, but no luck.

Comment: @ZlateWay which program? `pdf2djvu`? you must launch it from a console and not by double clicking the executable. Refer to the manual page https://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/wiki/ManualPage for help with the arguments.

Comment: @Pincopallino Can you write the steps for that? I opened the one with the graphical interface and but no luck.

Comment: @ZlateWay I edited the question with the instructions for the command line version. It might seem more complex, but it's better in my opinion. If you need to convert a lot of files, I can help you with a script that automates things a bit.